# How to write "Hello Word" with dd?

Tags: linux, dd

How to write "Hello Word" with dd?

Are there any tricks to create a txt file with dd that has a "Hello Word" in it?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Please include some motivation in the question.

Answer (score 13):

`dd` does not *generate* content (except for the space or zero padding that it can do with some options), its job is to read data from somewhere and write it somewhere else in the specified manners.

By default, `dd` writes on its stdout what it reads from its stdin. So the simplest you can do would be (as shell code).

```
dd << EOF > file
Hello World
EOF
```

`dd` reads its stdin (here, a here document provided by the shell) 512 bytes at a time, and writes it on its stdout (here open by the shell on `file`).

It can open the output file by itself:

```
dd of=file << EOF
Hello World
EOF
```

It can do some transformations, seek, read by smaller/larger chunks etc.

```
dd bs=1 skip=15 << EOF > file
Please output: Hello World
EOF
```

Or:

```
dd bs=12 count=1 conv=swab << EOF > file
eHll ooWlr
daft
EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `dd`  and `echo`:

```
echo -n "Hello World" | dd cbs=1 conv=unblock 2> /dev/null
```

sample output:

```
H
e
l
l
o

W
o
r
l
d
```

Other examples [from here](https://linuxconfig.org/learning-linux-commands-dd):

```
echo "MY UPPER CASE TEXT" | dd conv=lcase > your-txt-file
```

the output;

```
$ cat your-txt-file
MY UPPER CASE TEXT
```